# Growing BorderPane based on child's Textnode content in JavaFX

Tags: 3d, javafx, resize, 2d, textnode

I have a problem figuering out what the best procedure would be, to have a growing and shrinking `BorderPane`. I want to try and enlarge or shrink the Pane horizontally, based on a `Text` node child it has (with changing text length). There are some additional constraints / problems that I have to consider:

- Can not use a `Label`, because they render worse in a 3D scene. Even with lcd / gray / Cache on or off.
- The Text node does a linewrapping, if the text length is bigger than its bounding box width
- Using `setWrappingWidth(0)` automatically right align's the Text node instead of the horizontal center alignment I need.
- Using `setWrappingWidht(Double.MAX_VALUE)` throws exception in 3D scene when passing by with camera.
- Have not figuered out how to actually set the width of the node. I can get it with `getLayoutBounds().getWidth()`.
- The Text Node class doesn't seem to have any usable width bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing around for a while I found this answer: [Javafx textfield resize to text lenght?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737829/javafx-textfield-resize-to-text-lenght/18608568#18608568) It contains a method for computing the width of text. I changed my `BorderPane` to contain a `VBox`, which in turn contains a `TextField`. However it should also work by setting the `setWrappingWidth` for the `Text` node.
The `TextUtils` class I copied from above link.

```
public TextField getTop() {
    Node topNode = this.borderPane.getTop();
    if((topNode instanceof VBox)) {
        VBox topVBox = (VBox) topNode;
        if(!topVBox.getChildren().isEmpty() && topVBox.getChildren().get(0) instanceof TextField) {
            return (TextField) topVBox.getChildren().get(0);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void adaptWidthByText(Font font, String text) {
    // + 50px for some additional space to compensate insets, borders etc.
    double newWidth = TextUtils.computeTextWidth(font, text, 0.0D) + 50;
    this.borderPane.setPrefWidth(newWidth);
}

public void setTopText(String text) {
    TextField topTextField = getTop();
    if(topTextField == null) return;
    adaptWidthByText(topTextField.getFont(), text);
    topTextField.setText(text);
}
```