# Move to next scene/page with just pressing a number

Tags: java

I have develop a game in Java where user count the number of animals present in the image. There are 10 images arrange sequentially and user only need to input the number in JTextField and it will automatically go to the next image. What should I do?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

    if(!textField.getText().equals("")){
        total_test += 1;
        if(isNumeric(textField.getText())){
            //********************Correct Integer**********************
            if(Integer.valueOf(imgNo[randomNo])==Integer.valueOf(textField.getText())){
                //********************Correct Answer**********************
                System.out.println("Correct");
                sum+=1;
            }else{
                //********************Incorrect Answer**********************
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
                Error+=1;
            }
            refreshFrame();
        }else{
            //********************Incorrect Integer/Alphabet**********************
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            Error+=1;
            refreshFrame();
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Null Input");
    }
    //System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(imgNo[randomNo]));
}
public void refreshFrame(){
    if(total_test>=10){
        // add result page to see how many score
        //Task2(sum, Error);
        System.out.println("Correct: "+sum+" Incorrect: "+Error);
        frame.dispose();
    }else{
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        Task(inputID);
    }

}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Task1 a = new Task1(inputID);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
          Integer.valueOf(str);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;  
      }  
      return true;  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a value change listener to the JTextField 
Like

```
 textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        //Add code to change scene
      }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         //Add code to change scene 
      }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         //

Add code to change scene
  }
```